# How to send js variable to Spring controller?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I have this html code

```
<button onclick="var pdata = $('textarea').froalaEditor('html.get');">Submit article</button>
```

So I want to send this **pdata** variable to controller. How do I do this? Or should I use a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already use `jQuery`, consider the [jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) method.

```
$.post("controller/path", pdata)
    .done(function(response) {
      comsole.log("Response: " + response);
    });
```

You could move this code to a function, for example, like this:

```
<button onclick="submitArticle()">Submit article</button>
```

and in JS:

```
function submitArticle() {
    var pdata = $('textarea').froalaEditor('html.get');
    $.post("controller/path", pdata).done(function(response) {
        comsole.log("Response: " + response);
    });
}
```

Note that according to jQuery docs your `pdata` should be

> A plain object or string that is sent to the server with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Hey here is working example of post action ajax+jquery

consider one textfield and one button for example

MyButton

see following ajax call:

```
function updatData() {
var value= $("#sample").val();
$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url :"url",
data : {id:value},
timeout : 100000,
success : function(response) {
alert(response);   
 },
error : function(e) {
console.log("ERROR: ", e);
display(e);},
done : function(e) {
console.log("DONE");
 }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#button").click(function(){

$.ajax({
type : "POST",
url :"url",
data : {id: $("#field").val()},
timeout : 100000,
success : function(response) {
alert(response);   
},
error : function(e) {
console.log("ERROR: ", e);
display(e);},
done : function(e) {
console.log("DONE");
}
```

});