# SpringBoot. Thymeleaf. How to make table's column clickable to send request to Controller?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf

I've created table with 8 columns:

```html
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr height="30">
        <div th:each="horiz1, state : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}">
            <td width="30" th:value=${state.count} th:attr="action=@{/}" >
            </td>
        </div>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

In fact each column (tag "td") should serve as a button and after clicking send me to controller (@PostMapping or @GetMapping), where I will try to read th:value. **How to make it?**

Instead of th:attr="action=@{/}" I've tried to use th:href="@{/}" - does not work.
I've tried to insert between tags "td" the Form Button, but could not make it invisible and with size on complete size of column.

**UPD**. Full html code

```html
<body>  
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <div th:each="vert : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 4)}"> 
      <tr height="30">
        <div th:each="horiz1, state : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}">
            <td width="30" th:value=${state.count} th:attr="action=@{/}" th:style="${state.odd}? 'background: #f4cd8d' : 'background: #745853'">
            </td>
        </div>
      </tr>
      <tr height="30">
        <div th:each="horiz2, state : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}">
            <td width="30" th:style="${state.even}? 'background: #f4cd8d' : 'background: #745853' ">&nbsp;</td>
        </div>
      </tr>
     </div> 
    </table>
</body>
```

I'm creating chess board. After clicking at any cell, it should go to Controller, make some calculations and highlite cell, where a horse can move.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here. Some notes: (a) A `<td>` tag does not represent a column. It represents a cell. (b) Are you referring to `<th>` for column headers? (c) The question talks about `<th>` elements, but there are no such elements in your HTML fragment. (d) I would not use a `<div>` inside a `<tr>` element - instead place the `th:each` in the `<tr>` tag. See the [official documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#using-theach).

Comment: Maybe if you show the end result (some HTML after it has been rendered by Thymeleaf) we would get a better understanding of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: yep, feels like I've badly explained. I've added full code of html body (see above). there is no tag "th". when I've told "th" I mean thymeleaf. And yes: "td" means cell. So, clicking on cell, I want to go to Controller, where I want to get number of this cell. ..if you see better way to resolve this task, please, advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simplify the Thymeleaf**

Parts of this may not be directly relevant to your core question, but there is a lot you can do to simplify the Thymeleaf which generates the chess table.

By doing this, you can get rid of all the `<div>` elements you are currently using, and also make it easier to handle click events, later on:

```html
<table id="chessboard" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr height="30"
        th:each="row, rStat : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}">
        <td th:each="col, cStat : ${#numbers.sequence(1, 8)}"
            width="30" 
            th:data-row=${rStat.count} 
            th:data-col=${cStat.count} 
            th:style="${(rStat.odd and cStat.odd) or (rStat.even and cStat.even)} 
            ? 'background: #f4cd8d' : 'background: #745853'">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The main differences here are:

- I place the Thymeleaf `th:each` iterators in the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.
- I only have one piece of logic to handle coloring each square.
- I create two `data-` attributes in each `<td>` to uniquely identify each square.

Just to note:

You could argue that there is not much benefit from using Thymeleaf here, since basically everything is hard-coded in the Thymeleaf template. Normally, you would expect Thymeleaf to receive values from the controller - but for drawing the chess board, no such server-provided data is needed.

It does allow for a more compact template, I suppose.

---

**Clicking each Square**

The resulting HTML generated by the above Thymeleaf has no click events. It's easier to add these events immediately following table HTML, in a `<script>...</script>` tag - for example:

```js
// get an array containing the <td> elements
var squares = document.getElementsByTagName('td');

// loop through that array, adding an event to each element:
for (i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
  squares[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log('clicked on row ' + this.getAttribute('data-row') 
        + ' col ' + this.getAttribute('data-col'));
  });
}
```

In my case, the click events just cause a line of informational text to be printed to the browser's console - for example:

[image]

In your case, you want to send this data (the row and column numbers) to your controller. That is a much bigger question.

If you are not familiar with how to do this, you can research various questions - for example: [How to send js variable to Spring controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48612551/12567365) - and probably many more similar questions.

If you get stuck, you can ask a new, more targeted, follow-up question.